# Find indexes of sublists that contain a value

Tags: scheme

Let's say we have the following list :

```
'( (1 2 3) (3 4 5) (7 8 9) (2 9 9) )
```

I need to create a list with all the indexes from sublists that contain a give value, e.g.  for **2** ,  the result will be `'(0 3)` .It is a homework assignment and we are not allowed to use loops. It is simple to solve this using recursion, but I would like to use functionals but I don't know if that's possible (without using global variables, **set!** and any other lateral functions). Any hints / suggestions are welcomed !

Comment: what does the term "functionals" mean in this setting?

Comment: @JohnClements foldr, foldl, map, apply, filter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely solve this problem with foldl. Foldl can be used to model any loop-like traversal of a list.

Honestly, the clearest way to understand how to use foldl for a problem like this is first to write it in a simple recursive way, following the [design recipe](http://www.ccis.northeastern.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/). You should be careful to use the `rest` of the list only in the recursive call.

Next, you'd want to refactor the program so that it makes only tail calls; that is, if you're defining a function called `f`, the "cons" case should be `(f ...)`, with nothing "outside" of it. In order to make this possible, you're allowed to introduce one extra argument for your function, often called the 'accumulator'. The result of the function in the empty case should probably just be the accumulator. At this point, changing to a use of `foldl` is just a matter of calling `foldl` with the list, the initial value of the accumulator, and the function that takes the first element of the list and the accumulator and produces the new accumulator.

Whew!

Comment: the main problem is that I do not know how to calculate the iteration step in order to create that list of indexes. I tried using 1 more variable as a counting value, but foldl does not work with other than list of same sizes.

Comment: @DaniMocanu How about `(foldl (lambda (index element acc) ...) (range (length lst)) lst)`?

Comment: @DaniMocanu you can "bundle" two values into one using e.g. a list or cons. Yes, this is irritating.